# Keeping integer addition within bounds

Tags: c, integer

I have to read a `int8_t` from a buffer, read a `uint8_t` from the camera's current settings, add them together, keep new value within the bounds 0 to 100 and write the new value to the camera's current settings. This seems quite easy to me, and yet here I have a rather large bit of code.

The brace style is company-mandated.

Is there a way to remove some of the complexity from this code?

Ranges:
`plusZoomPercentage`: full range of `int8_t`.
`currentZoomPercentage` and `getZoomPercentage()`: 0 to 100, 0 and 100 included.
`newZoomPercentage`: To be between 0 and 100, 0 and 100 included.

Header file:

```
/*Zooms to the provided percentage of maximum zoom level.*/
void zoomToPercentage(uint8_t percentage);

/*Retrieves the current targeted percentage of maximum zoom level (if the camera is currently at 50% zoom, but is zooming towards 60%, return 60.)*/
uint8_t getZoomPercentage();
```

Calling implementation:

```
int8_t plusZoomPercentage;
if (!unabto_query_read_int8(readBuffer, &plusZoomPercentage))
{
    return AER_REQ_TOO_SMALL;
}
if (plusZoomPercentage == 0) 
{ 
    return AER_REQ_RESPONSE_READY;
}
uint8_t currentZoomPercentage = getZoomPercentage();
uint8_t newZoomPercentage = currentZoomPercentage + plusZoomPercentage;
if (plusZoomPercentage > 0)
{
    /*Check for overflow or otherwise going out of bounds*/
    if (newZoomPercentage > 100 || newZoomPercentage < currentZoomPercentage)
    {
        zoomToPercentage(100);
    }
    else 
    {
        zoomToPercentage(newZoomPercentage);
    }
}
else
{
    if (newZoomPercentage > currentZoomPercentage)
    {
        zoomToPercentage(0);
    }
    else
    {
        zoomToPercentage(newZoomPercentage);
    }
}
return AER_REQ_RESPONSE_READY;
```

Comment: do the input values have any bounds? Like the camera setting and buffer never getting above 100 themselves?

Comment: @ratchetfreak Moved the ranges and other related info to the question so people don't have to dig in the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will be a bit shorter and simpler without the duplicated `else` blocks:

```
if (plusZoomPercentage > 0)
{
    /*Check for overflow or otherwise going out of bounds*/
    if (newZoomPercentage > 100 || newZoomPercentage < currentZoomPercentage)
    {
        newZoomPercentage = 100;
    }
}
else if (newZoomPercentage > currentZoomPercentage)
{
    newZoomPercentage = 0;
}
zoomToPercentage(newZoomPercentage);
return AER_REQ_RESPONSE_READY;
```

Comment: Even after looking at it several times I have nothing else to say than "yep, that's true. That'll work."

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, instead of bounding the result, you should bound the difference. Min and Max are your friend.... Consider the following:

```
if (plusZoomPercentage != 0)
{
    uint8_t currentZoomPercentage = getCurrentZoom();
    // cannot zoom to less than 0
    plusZoomPercentage = max(plusZoomPercentage, - currentZoomPercentage);
    // cannot zoom to more than 100
    plusZoomPercentage = min(plusZoomPercentage, 100 - currentZoomPercentage);

    zoomToPercentage(currentZoomPercentage + plusZoomPercentage);
}
return AER_REQ_RESPONSE_READY;
```

Since your current zoom is consistently bound to 0 and 100, you can rely on bounding the difference only.

See this running [in ideone.](http://ideone.com/BI5yXc)

Comment: Where are `max` and `min` coming from?

Comment: I see, you've defined them yourself...

Answer (score 1):

By changing the types of `currentZoomPercentage` and `newZoomPercentage` to `int16_t`, you don't have to worry about certain types of overflows:

```
int16_t newZoomPercentage = getZoomPercentage() + plusZoomPercentage;

if (newZoomPercentage > 100)
    newZoomPercentage = 100;
else if (newZoomPercentage < 0)
    newZoomPercentage = 0;
zoomToPercentage(newZoomPercentage);
```

Comment: This has to work on an embedded device, where I'd like to keep my datatypes small. Use of an `int16_t` for `newZoomPercentage` could make the code smaller, indeed.

Comment: Ok I see.  What size registers do you have on your cpu?  You should be able to use the same size `int` as your register size with no additional wasted code size or storage.